# Constraints w/ Recursive Postgres Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to skip a certain city as I traverse my data. Currently, this query works to find all available flights from SLC to LA, including trips with layovers. You'll see this in the picture below.

[image: flights from SLC to LA]

However, I want to be able to exclude certain cities in a flight plan. For example, if Montreal is a stop between SLC and LA, that trip wouldn't be considered.
I've tried putting various things in the WHERE clauses, but to no avail. Any other suggestions? Sample data an queries are given below.

```
WITH RECURSIVE segs AS (
  SELECT f0.flight_num::text as flight
            , src_city, dest_city
            , dep_time AS departure
            , arr_time AS arrival
            , airfare, mileage
            , 1 as hops
            , (arr_time - dep_time)::interval AS total_time
            , '00:00'::interval as waiting_time
  FROM flight f0
  WHERE src_city = 'SLC' -- <SRC_CITY>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.flight || '-->' || f1.flight_num::text as flight
            , s.src_city, f1.dest_city
            , s.departure AS departure
            , f1.arr_time AS arrival
            , s.airfare + f1.airfare as airfare
            , s.mileage + f1.mileage as mileage
            , s.hops + 1 AS hops
            , s.total_time + (f1.arr_time - f1.dep_time)::interval AS total_time
            , s.waiting_time + (f1.dep_time - s.arrival)::interval AS waiting_time
  FROM segs s
     JOIN flight f1
       ON f1.src_city = s.dest_city
       AND f1.dep_time > s.arrival -- you can't leave until you are there
)
SELECT *
FROM segs
WHERE dest_city = 'LA' -- <DEST_CITY>
ORDER BY airfare desc
    ;

create table flight
  ( flight_num BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , src_city varchar
  , dest_city varchar
  , dep_time TIME
  , arr_time TIME
  , airfare INTEGER
  , mileage INTEGER
);

insert into flight VALUES
  (101,    'Montreal',          'NY',                   '05:30',     '06:45',    180,      170),
  (102,    'Montreal',          'Washington',           '01:00',     '02:35',    100,      180),
  (103,    'NY',                'Chicago',              '08:00',     '10:00',    150,      300),
  (105,    'Washington',        'KansasCity',           '06:00',     '08:45',    200,      600),
  (106,    'Washington',        'NY',                   '12:00',     '13:30',     50,       80),
  (107,    'Chicago',           'SLC',                  '11:00',     '14:30',    220,      750),
  (110,    'KansasCity',        'Denver',               '14:00',     '15:25',    180,      300),
  (111,    'KansasCity',        'SLC',                  '13:00',     '15:30',    200,      500),
  (112,    'SLC',               'SanFran',              '18:00',     '19:30',     85,      210),
  (113,    'SLC',               'LA',                   '17:30',     '19:00',    185,      230),
  (115,    'Denver',            'SLC',                  '15:00',     '16:00',     75,      300),
  (116,    'SanFran',           'LA',                   '22:00',     '22:30',     50,       75),
  (118,    'LA',                'Seattle',              '20:00',     '21:00',    150,      450);
```

Comment: This is up to your customer, really. He should be the one to define the proper criteria.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20051387/905902 IMHO you haven't put too much effort into this new question.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude certain cities from the flight plan you should add where clauses at 2 places in your query as following:

1. Right after src_city condition

   > ```
   > ... 
   > WHERE src_city = 'SLC' -- <SRC_CITY>
   > AND dest_city <> 'Montreal'
   > ...
   > ```
2. In the recursive join condition

   > ```
   > ...
   > AND f1.dep_time > s.arrival -- you can't leave until you are there
   > AND f1.dest_city <> 'Montreal'
   > ...
   > ```

   I don't have Postgress but I tried it with SQL server and it seems to work.